# What is the meaning of "grano de arena" in "tratar de, desde este esquina, poner nuestro grano de arena en el desarrollo del país"

Tags: significado

I'm translating a transcript from an interview in Spanish and my client is set on using a phrase that doesn't feel right. The translation will be used in the caption of a video so its length is very important.

The original text is:

> Tratar de, desde esta esquina, poner nuestro grano de arena en el desarrollo del país.

He wants to use: *To be able to **contribute our small part to** the growth of this country.* Text in bold is the text in question. I propose "contribute to the growth..." or "play a part in the growth..."

Comment: Google translate suggests, instead: Tratar de, desde esta esquina, poner nuestro _granito_ de arena en el desarrollo del país, which comes out as the more sensible: Try, from this corner, to do our bit in the development of the country.

Comment: @cag51 thanks for the migration, we did not have a question about "grano de arena" so it is a good addition. However (for the future), note that "idiomatic translations" **to English** are off-topic here, as we are supposed to be experts on the Spanish language. I'll go ahead and edit the question to make it on-topic.

Comment: in fact, the question could also be moved to [english.se], where they have similar questions with [idiom-requests] and [spanish] tags.

Answer (score 5):

Finding idiomatic translations *to English* is not really our specialty, so I will just explain what the sentence means. *Grano de arena* (or *granito de arena*) is defined [on DLE](https://dle.rae.es/grano) as

> 1. m. Aportación a una obra o fin determinado que quien la hace presenta, por modestia, como pequeña.

i.e., a contribution to a certain project or goal that is **modestly presented by the contributor as a small one**.

So a translation of the sentence

- Tratar de, desde esta esquina, poner nuestro grano de arena en el desarrollo del país.

should include this idea that the contribution is *small*. Therefore, both the translation proposed in [Buffy's comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/37039/idiomatic-translation-for-tratar-de-desde-este-esquina-poner-nuestro-grano-de#comment64479_37039):

- Try, from this corner, to do our bit in the development of the country

and your friend's suggestion using "our small part" are fine. What is most idiomatic in English, as I said, I do not know.

Comment: I think in context do our bit is the more natural.

Comment: In addition, I've seen the use of "And that's my 2 cents." when someone tries to add modesty to their contribution.  Not necessarily meaning it is small or of small value.

Comment: “Add or put in your two penn'orth” (contracted form of *‘two pennyworth’*) is a similar colloquial expression in British English, although probably not heard very much these days.